# Употребление слова "мелирование"

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов, терминология

Можно ли сказать: "Чёрные волосы, мелированные красными прядями"? Или "мелированные красным"?

Comment: Мне кажется, в профессиональном сленге даже так и придётся сказать. Интересно, что в словаре Кузнецова - "осветление" (т.е. как быть с красным?). Но с францзуского mêler - смешивать что угодно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Мелирование — способ окрашивания волос, а точнее, осветление
>   отдельными прядями.

Так что можно осветлять брюнетку и цветом, и прядями этого цвета.